# How can I combine clean and make to create a "Rebuild" task using tasks.json in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a Visual Studio Code project where I have defined custom make all and make clean build tasks.

How can I create a new task "rebuild" which will combine these tasks so as to run make clean followed by make all.

My current tasks.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": 
[
    {
        "label": "make debug",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make",
        // use options.cwd property if the Makefile is not in the project root ${workspaceRoot} dir
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/Debug"
        },
        // start the build without prompting for task selection, use "group": "build" otherwise
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared"
        },

        // arg passing example: make all
        "args": ["all", "-B"],
        // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": ["absolute"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        },

    },
    {
        "label": "make clean debug",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make",
        // use options.cwd property if the Makefile is not in the project root ${workspaceRoot} dir
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/Debug"
        },
        // start the build without prompting for task selection, use "group": "build" otherwise
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared"
        },

        // arg passing example: make all
        "args": ["clean", "-B"],
        // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": ["absolute"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Realistically this is more of a nice to have but I would really like to know how to do this.

I don't want to add any external scripts or helpers, I would like to just use VS for this task.

I did check the documentation here and search around SO but I haven't found what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a new task, but with args like below?

```
"args": [
    "clean", "all" 
],
```

Comment: This gives make target "clean all" which can be problematic. This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978878/visual-studio-code-needs-explicit-clean-and-build